# Android: using Twitter API 1.1 oAuth

Tags: java, android, oauth, twitter

I would like to do simple twitter search in an Android app without user authentication that is possible with API 1.0, but now I see that API 1.1 requires using authentication. Is there a simple tutorial on how to use oAuth in Java? I can't seem to find one that keeps things simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the OAuth implementation for twitte4j, or even use twitter4j on your Android application: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library for this exact problem, very simple and lightweight https://github.com/twotoasters/AndrOAuth